# App crashes when use ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

I am having an app which extends Activity, now I am implementing the Action bar so now I have modified to extends ActionBarActivity. When I run the code my app getting crash, why app gets crash after extending the ActionBarActivity?

> 06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773): Process: com.test.activitymanager, PID: 27773
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at com.test.activity.ui.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:210)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>   06-30 15:51:24.215: E/AndroidRuntime(27773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/header_new"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnhelp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu"
                android:background="@drawable/help_icon"
                android:visibility="visible" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtActivtyTypeHeader"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnhelp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/Activity"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:typeface="sans" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRecordMileage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_images"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/mileage"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddViewCMAttachment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnRecordMileage"
                android:background="@drawable/attachment_icon"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSiteDetails"
                    style="@style/action_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_images_black"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/SiteDetails"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/noSiteDetail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_site_details_found"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutSiteDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/SiteName"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvSiteName"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".45" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgMapMarker"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".15"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                            android:src="@drawable/map_marker" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/Address"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".45" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/iBtnWheather"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".15"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                            android:src="@drawable/btn_wheather" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/Coordinates"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvCoordinates"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnActivityDetails"
                    style="@style/action_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
                    android:background="@drawable/button_images_black"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/ActivityDetails" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutActivityDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/sow_tag"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvSOW"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/Status1"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/DateScheduled"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDateScheduled"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/DurationWorkBegan"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDurationWorkBegan"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/createdBy"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvCreatedBy"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:text="@string/Remarks"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etRemarks"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".6"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                            android:inputType="none" >
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutButtonContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="1" 
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                        android:src="@drawable/play_button_with_icon" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                        android:src="@drawable/pause_button_with_icon" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                        android:src="@drawable/stop_button_with_icon" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutspButtonContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnApproceActivity"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                        android:src="@drawable/approved" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnRejectActivity"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Action"
                        android:src="@drawable/rejected" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlsHelpLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/update_activity_help_screen_cm"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> 

```
I am using the Eclipse: under libs folder the below jars are there: android-support-v4.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
date4j.jar
gcm.jar
google-play-services.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
httpmime-4.2.5.jar
imagezoom.jar

and I have added one more 3 rd library project to my project.
```

Comment: Please, provide your xml layout

Comment: Try 'extends AppCompatActivity' instead and see if you get the same result

Comment: It is now `AppCompatActivity` withh v22+ of AppCompat v7 support library. Please show xml layout and which theme you use. The theme style shall derive from `Theme.AppCompat`. If you use `Toolbar` which is not an `ActionBar` but behaves and enhances ActionBar's features, the theme shall come from any `Theme.AppCompat.*.*.NoActionBar`

Comment: Applied the theme to my app:   Theme.AppCompat.Light and AppCompatActivity does not work same error

Comment: Post your build.gradle and the jars used in libs folder

Answer (score 1):

My Issue got resolved, removed android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" which is applied to my actvitiy and app theme style added to Theme.AppCompat and removed the v-13 support library